# How to test parent child relationship in react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Lets say this is my HTML, created from using semantic-ui.

I select number 35 from my dropdown and the result becomes this:

```html
<div name="genre" style="width:400px" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" class="ui compact fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
  <a class="ui label" value="35">Comedy<i aria-hidden="true" class="delete icon"></i></a>

  <div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="true" class="selected item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Comedy</span></div>
</div>
```

Ideally I want to test the parent items children like this:

- parent: name="genre"
- child: value="35", text = Comedy

This doesn't seem possible.

I can only test one selector level for example - by `getByText('Comedy')` which is too generic since there are other 'Comedy' elements on the same page.

So how to select something like this:

```
getByWhatever('Some parent').getChildByWhatever('Some child').exists()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`within`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/) query to get elements within another specific element.

```js
const combobox = screen.getByRole('combobox'); // Retrieve the parent
expect(combobox).toHaveAttribute('name', 'genre');
const link = within(combobox).getByRole('link', { name: 'Comedy' }); // Retrieve the link child from within the parent
expect(link).toHaveAttribute('value', '35');
```

Comment: Excellent. That works great. Though I'm curious why  screen.getByRole('combobox', {name: 'genre'}) is causing an error. This api says I can use it: https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/

Comment: When using `getByRole` query, the `name` refers to the element's accessible name, not the name property. That's why it fails in this case.

Comment: oh like aria-lable?

Comment: Yes, like having an aria-label on the element to provide an accessible name.